# How to post Swagger API documentation to Atlassian Confluence programmatically? (Usage of Swagger Confluence tool and Confluence REST API)

Tags: swagger, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to upload my Swagger JSON schema (myapi.json) into Atlassian Confluence using the [swagger](https://cloud.slkdev.net/swagger-confluence/)-[confluence](https://github.com/starlightknight/swagger-confluence) standalone [tool](https://cloud.slkdev.net/artifactory/ext-release-local/net/slkdev/swagger/confluence/swagger-confluence-cli-all/2.2-RELEASE/swagger-confluence-cli-all-2.2-RELEASE.jar).

The standalone CLI .jar [should](https://cloud.slkdev.net/swagger-confluence/cli/) (according to my understanding) operate like this (used [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html) page for credentials Base64 encoding):

```
java -jar <system path root>/swagger-confluence-cli-all-2.2-RELEASE.jar -u "http(s)://<server>:<port>/confluence/rest/api/" -b "<base64 encoded userid:password string" -a "<parent page id>" -k "<space key>" -g "true" -i "true" -s "<myschema.json>" -t "<Title for generated page>" -m "single"
```

Output (404 Not found):

```
2016-08-23 15:08:12.177  INFO - [main]  n.s.s.c.s.i.SwaggerToAsciiDocServiceImpl : AsciiDoc Conversion Complete!  
2016-08-23 15:08:12.178  INFO - [main] n.s.s.c.s.i.AsciiDocToXHtmlServiceImpl   : Converting AsciiDoc to XHTML5...
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated   
2016-08-23 15:08:16.888  INFO - [main] n.s.s.c.s.i.AsciiDocToXHtmlServiceImpl   : XHTML5 Conversion Complete!   
2016-08-23 15:08:17.728  INFO - [main] n.s.s.c.s.i.XHtmlToConfluenceServiceImpl : Posting XHTML to Confluence...
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

It's caused a bit of confusion while searching for Confluence REST API examples, e.g. in Stackoverflow, as the API seems to have been changing some. However, Confluence REST API [page](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api) suggests the current API should have been the same since Confluence Server 5.5. This is also described as a requirement in the swagger-confluence overview [page](https://cloud.slkdev.net/swagger-confluence/).

The same requirements mention "A Confluence User with access to the REST API". How is this determined? I'm using an admin user. I found the general "Enable Remote API" configuration (which seemed to be enabled as default) under General Configuration -> Further Configuration as described in this [article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/enabling-the-remote-api-150460.html). The same article says the XML-RPC and SOAP APIs this setting enables are deprecated on Confluence 5.5+. Is the REST API enabled by default and is there a means to control the usage?

Also getting a bit weird results when trying to call the REST API (although I **do** get responses so that leads me to think the URL is correct).

```
curl -v -u userid:pass http://<server>:<port>/confluence/rest/api/  
...  
HTTP/1.1 302 Found  
...
```

But calling the URL `http://<server>:<port>/confluence/rest/api/` with REST Easy (Firefox Plugin) with GET and providing userid & pass as Basic Authentication returns 200 OK HTTP status and seems to return my Confluence Dashboard (parent of the spaces; top-level page). Same also happens when accessing the URL with just browser.

Also numerous other attempts at calling the Confluence REST [API](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/5.8.14/) with documented ways resulted in 404. Starting to think this is an authorization issue.. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a another way to produce results similar to Swagger Confluence [demo](https://confluence.slkdev.net/display/DEMO/%5BS%5D+Swagger+Pet+Store)?

Answer (score 7):

Well, turns out even though `http://<server>:<port>/confluence/rest/api/` returned HTTP 200 OK, **the URL was wrong.**
The above is the so called "URL with context" (the /confluence/ part) and what I needed was the URL without context (no /confluence/ in the URL).

Here's how I tested the URL working by receiving the 200, Headers (-v) and page content as JSON response:
`curl -v -u user:pass http://<server>:<port>/rest/api/content/{id}`
The page ID can be checked by pressing (or mouse-overing) the "Edit" button on the Confluence page.

And here's how I finally got the automatic Confluence upload working:
`java -jar <system path root>/swagger-confluence-cli-all-2.2-RELEASE.jar -u "http(s)://<server>:<port>/rest/api/" -b "<base64 encoded userid:password string>" -a "<parent page id>" -k "<space key>" -g "true" -i "true" -s "<myschema.json>" -t "<Title for generated page>" -m "single"`

The Swagger Confluence [tool](https://cloud.slkdev.net/swagger-confluence/cli/) is awesome, by the way, and the results are as good as in the [demo](https://confluence.slkdev.net/display/DEMO/%5BS%5D+Swagger+Pet+Store)!

[Edited to add]:
Confirmed the Swagger Confluence library/tool (v2.2) to work on both my target Confluence Servers, versions 5.8.14 and 5.9.2

Comment: tool is no longer available and demo link is dead, hence downvoted... please fix or remove answer.

Comment: the tool is still available at https://github.com/starlightknight/swagger-confluence but seems not to be maintenanced anymore